# Connect Samsung S4 to laptop and show hidden items in gallery

Tags: android

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 (Android KitKat). I have used the `Hide items` in Gallery app to hide some pictures. Now the LCD of my phone is broken and I cant see anything on the screen. But, I can connect the phone to my HP laptop (Windows 7, 64 bit) using USB cable to recover my data, I can see all data, pictures, music, etc.

The problem is that the hidden items are not shown using the mass storage. Note that the `Show hidden items` of `Folder Options` is enabled on my laptop.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. I suppose you're using Windows, but it is always better to specify the versions for the Operative System and the programs that you are using in order to help who want to give you an answer. Please [edit] your answer adding those details.

Comment: Are you using any samsung software to access to it? From Linux it's possible to see the phone as an usb device. There was some option to enable but I suppose you have just enabled it. The pictures are saved by default in `/Device Storage/DCIM/Camera` or in `/SD card/DCIM/Camera`... if you can reach those directories you have an high probability to see all the pictures. Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually Im using windows and I can see the phone as a USB storage, and I can see all pictures and music and data, except those that I hide from my phone

Comment: You're welcome. [Here](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Hidden-Pictures-on-Android)  they remember that in Linux an hidden file is each file that starts with `.`. So `Image1.jpg` can be simply renamed in `.Image1.jpg`. They suggest too that they can be moved in a different, maybe hidden, directory. Did you just tried to do a full research for `jpg` files... on that device?

Comment: Yes I did, Also I connected my phone to a Linux Ubuntu, and I tried to show hidden files but nothing appear :(

Comment: If you will not find a solution before remember me this problem posting a comment @hastur here the next week and I will see if I can do something more. They have to be somewhere. Remember that under Linux they are hidden. So `ls -a` ...